# Undefined symbol std::__throw_bad_function_call

Tags: c++, stl, linker, g++

I'm building C++ code in Eclipse CDT with g++ and I'm getting the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__throw_bad_function_call()", referenced from:
      std::function<void (graphics::RenderingContext*)>::operator()(graphics::RenderingContext*) const in GameWindow.o
```

I have `std::function` members in a class called GameWindow.

Is there something I have to link to in order to get code using `std::function` to link properly?

Comment: I came across similar problem. I searched online and found that it occurs when you miss to include any internal headers.Hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out my lib path wasn't set correctly for g++.

For posterity: I use gcc 4.7 for compiling because I need C++11 features.  XCode (on OS X Mountain Lion), ships with gcc 4.2 so I installed gcc 4.7 through Homebrew.

For Eclipse to compile with gcc 4.7, I had to change the path to the compiler and linker in project settings to correspond to the newly installed via Homebrew version.  However, I still had the old library path to the gcc 4.2 stdlibc++ in my project settings.

Comment: Right, I added that function in about 2009, so you must have been linking against an older `libstdc++` from an older G++ version, which didn't provide the symbol. If you use `g++` to link it should find the right lib automatically.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Exactly what was happening.  I was still linking against the gcc 4.2 libstdc++ from XCode, when I was actually compiling and linking with gcc 4.7.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If this is your only error, why you don't try to implement that function in your own code? something like:

```
namespace std {
    void __throw_bad_function_call() {throw bad_function_call("invalid function called");}
}
```

Comment: In embedded SW standard library is often not used due to the library size. In this case @BigBoss proposal is a right option. `namespace std {void __throw_bad_function_call() { while(1); }; }` gives a little overhead but allows to use `std::function` templates.