# How to bind member function with std::function?

Tags: c++11

I want to bind member function, but it seems failed.

```
Q4kDeviceSource.hh
class Q4kDeviceSource {
public:
  void videoStreamCallback(QIPCamStreamCbType streamCbType, uint32_t streamId, uint8_t *buffer, size_t bufferSize);
。。。
}

typedef std::function<void(QIPCamStreamCbType cbType, uint32_t streamId,
                        uint8_t* buffer, size_t bufferSize)>
                        StreamCallback;

Q4kDeviceSource.cpp
。。。
StreamCallback videoElementryCb = std::bind(&Q4kDeviceSource::videoStreamCallback, this,
        std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4);

videoElementryCb(QIPCamStreamCbType::QIPCAM_STREAMCBTYPE_NORMAL,id,NULL,0);
。。。
```

**build failed！**

./prebuilts/ndk/9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/functional:2463: error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_bad_function_call()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942538/undefined-symbol-std-throw-bad-function-call

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you link with `gcc` instead of `g++`.

The difference is that `g++` also links in `libstdc++`, whereas `gcc` does not.

Either link with `g++` or add `-lstdc++` to your linker command line.